# How to Collect elements of the Stream with incosistent data into a Map?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have a method that receives a `List` of ***email**s* and ***id**s* as `String`s.

I am making an *API call* then which has a limit of `100` ***email*** searches per call:

```
userService.listUsersByEmails(List<String> emails)
```

It returns a list of `User` objects.

Currently, I am collecting the results into a single `List` of `User` objects.

```
 List<User> users=  Lists.partition(emails, 100)//
    .stream()
    .map(userService:: listUsersByEmails)// this method makes API calls which takes 100 
      .flatMap(List::stream)             // emails as params (comma separated) & returns 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());     // User objects for each email found
```

The `listUserByEmails` method returns `User` object for each email found in the **DB**.

But a few results might not have the `emailAddress` attribute, but they are guaranteed to have an `Id`, `firstName` and `LastName`.

I am hoping to create a ***map*** of type `Map<String, User>`s like that

```
Key (emailAddress) - "JohnDoe@test.com" , Value - John Doe's User object.
```

The `User` objects that gets returned looks like this

```
 {id: 123456789
    emailAddress: john.doe@dev.com
    firstName: John
    lastName: Doe
    displayName: Sharon
    title: null
    company:  DEVELOP
    username: s-dev
    location: null
    accountType: NORMAL}
```

Is there any option to handle all `User`s (with ***email*** and without) together in one go?

Comment: Is there a problem with `Collectors.toMap()`?

Comment: how can i map each email to its object ? like for example
Collectors.toMap(e-> emailString, e -> UserObject);

Comment: I don't know what `UserObject` looks like, but something like `toMap(user -> user.getEmailAddress(), user -> user)`.

Comment: thanks for that, i tried it, but as I mentioned, some users might not have emailAddress.
 Edited the question to show the User Object

Comment: What you should do with users which do not have email? Skip them?

Comment: @Eugene I am mapping them further so cannot skip them. Already skipping that I didnt find.

Comment: `userService.listUsersByEmails()` returns a list of comma-separated strings? How each element in the list is structured and what `User` constructor expects?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko userService.listUsersByEmails(List<String> emails)
It returns a list of User Objects. User being returned is in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will allow to handle all `User` objects in the stream regardless of whether they have an *email*.

`Collectors.partitioningBy` splits the data into two parts based on the given *predicate* (whether *email* is present or not), and returns map with a key of type `Boolean`.

Then, based on this map, the two district maps `userByEmail` and `userById` are being populated.

That's how both maps could be ***encapsulated*** in a `class` and accessed via an instance of this *class*:

```
public class UserStorage {
    private Map<String, User> userByEmail = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Long, User> userById = new HashMap<>();

    public void addUsers(List<User> source) {
        Map<Boolean, User> userByHasEmail = source
                .stream()
                .map(userService:: listUsersByEmails)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                        user -> user.getEmailAddress() != null && !user.getEmailAddress().isBlank(),
                        Function.identity()));

        for (Map.Entry<Boolean, User> entry: userByHasEmail.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey()) {
                userByEmail.put(entry.getValue().getEmailAddress(), entry.getValue());
            } else {
                userById.put(entry.getValue().getId(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public User getUser(String email) {
        return userByEmail.get(email);
    }

    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return userById.get(id);
    }

    public User getUser(String email, Long id) {
        return userByEmail.getOrDefault(email, userById.get(id));
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserStorage storage = new UserStorage();
    storage.addUsers(Lists.partition(emails, 100));

    User userWithEmail = storage.getUser("john.doe@dev.com");
    User userWithNoEmail = storage.getUser(123456789L);
    User user = storage.getUser("anyString", 123456789L);
}
```

Comment: It isn't well defined but the op said *`few results might not have emailAddress as the attribute`*.  So if the field is not null but empty or blank you may want to include `&& !user.getEmailAddress().isBlank()`

Comment: @Alexander Inanchenko - this is very much close to what i want to achieve. Apologies, but the only thing that is missing is that some searches(as mentioned in the question) for example - test@example will return the User object but it will have emailaddress = null (this is due to this user is outside our field and we dont want to reveal their email)
Is there a way to handles emailAddress = null as well in this ?Thats the actual thing I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by "handle"

Comment: @JainamShah `Is there a way to handles emailAddress = null as well in this` in the same map no. It has to be separate collection (like `Map<Long(ID), User>`) for that case. But as both maps can be encapsulated in single class. And *user* object could be retrieved in a single request (*by providing emeil and id*) to the instance of that class.

Comment: @JainamShah It would be a logical mistake to place users that can be accessed using different properties in one map. But it doesn't mean that `partition(emails, 100)` need to invoked twice for that. I'll show in a minute what I mean.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko - one more thing i tried after your suggestion - 
Map<User, List<User>> users=  Lists.partition(emails, 100)
                .stream()
                .map(UserService:: listUsersByEmails)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
But I want to group by String(emailAddress) -> Function.identity()

Comment: Meaning each input that went into listuserbyemail to its output

Comment: @JainamShah `User::getEmailAddress` instread of `Function.identity()`. But what benefit `Map<String(email), List<User>>` would bring? There must only one user mapped to a particular `Id`.

Comment: @JainamShah  Take a look at the code I've provided. You can handle all user with one call of the `partition` method. It could be done in a loop, merging maps of the same type together.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko - using User::getEmailAddress will fail because some of the user objects returned will have emailAddress = null. Also i am using this email -> uberobject to further process this data structure as its a search function based on emails for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243262/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-jainam-shah).

Comment: @JainamShah Sure, in order to user `email` as a key you need to discard users that don't have it. You didn't clarify you do you want to have `List<User>` as a value? And what do you think about the updated code? Two maps `userByEmail` and `userById`, all users are handled.